# Text content cross table in R

Tags: r

I need to create a pivot table in R that will have text values instead of aggregated SUM or AVERAGE functions. Something like in the example below:

Original table (in a dataframe with fields User, Field, Text):

**User  | Field | Text**

Group1  | Field 1   | Text content A
Group1  | Field 2   | Text content B
Group2  | Field 1   | Text content C
Group2  | Field 2   | Text content D
Group3  | Field 1   | Text content E

The result that I need in R using cross tabulation:

**User  | Field 1   |  Field 2**

Group1  | Text content A    | Text content B
Group2  | Text content C    |Text content D
Group3  | Text content E    |NA
I would then need to save the result as CSV... but that's the easy part:)

Is there any way of achieving this?

Many thanks,
MA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `reshape` (going from 'long' format to 'wide' format). Other people prefer the `reshape` package, but both will do for this simple case.

Here's a solution with the base function:

```
tmp<-data.frame(user=c("G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G3"), field=c("F1", "F2", "F1", "F2", "F1"), txt=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
reshape(data=tmp, direction="wide", timevar="field", idvar="user")
```

Comment: I did look in the reshape help but only found information on how to add aggregated values like I said in my initial message... I can't seem to find any information on how to add the text content... hence my message here. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick! it worked perfectly! I was actually trying to include the text value as an argument such as value="txt".. that's where I was going wrong. Many thanks again.